# wrong paging link redirection

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have applied the [class of pagination](http://www.jaygilford.com/php/completely-customisable-php-pagination-class) in the search result to page `search-result.php`. When i click on the number link of pages like 2 in  `1  2  3  4  5 ... 10`  then it redirects me to `index.php?page=2`. But the search paging result is shown on `search-result.php` page. The link should be `search-result.php?page=2`

This page (`search-result.php`) is also being used for url rewriting. rule is something like:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$  search-result.php?t=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$  search-result.php?t=$1&slug=$2 [L]`

Please help me about this issue. Thanks

Comment: You have to show some code of how you redirect and what the script does. If you need it to redirect to another page, it might not by much of a problem, but is it because you cannot change the link content?

Comment: "class of pagination" is used and it is rendering the link which are redirecting towards further pages.

Comment: i guess this is an issue by `<base href='index.php'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the "pagination" class by default redirects to an "index" page. I think it might help changing `$link_prefix` variable (on line 29 in the class file) from:

```
$link_prefix = '/?page=';
```

to

```
$link_prefix = '/search-result.php?page=';
```

You might either change this directly in the class or since this is a public variable, you might change it using "pagination" object.

Hope this helps.